# OroCommerce 1.6 overload/override customer dashboard

Tags: symfony-2.8, orocommerce

I followed this [link](https://oroinc.com/orocrm/forums/topic/how-to-override-parts-of-oro) and [this link](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/inheritance.html) to override or add new controller and methods in it. It wouldn't just work at all. There seem to be very less documentation or forum support. Can anyone help me please what is the proper way to overload the customer dashboard controller ?

It is giving me `No route found for "GET /customer/documents/"` error message.

Answer (score 2):

There is no route "/customer/documents/" in OroCommerce, so there is nothing to "override".

The customer dashboard ("My Account") page route is "/customer/profile/", see [routing.yml in OroCustomerBundle](https://github.com/oroinc/customer-portal/blob/2.6.0/src/Oro/Bundle/CustomerBundle/Resources/config/oro/routing.yml#L48-L53):

```
oro_customer_frontend_customer_user_profile:
    resource: "@OroCustomerBundle/Controller/Frontend/CustomerUserProfileController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /customer/profile
    options:
        frontend: true
```

which is served by [CustomerUserProfileController.php#L17-L31](https://github.com/oroinc/customer-portal/blob/2.6.0/src/Oro/Bundle/CustomerBundle/Controller/Frontend/CustomerUserProfileController.php#L17-L31)

If you are trying to create a new controller for "/customer/documents/" route, then simply create your controller, and define this new route in Resources/config/oro/routing.yml of your custom bundle.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thank you for the answer. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Michael I am trying to overload/extend the core "OroCustomerBundle" bundle to add a new action method "documentsAction". So I followed links mentioned above.